# Creating a shortcode by pulling in a custom field from a plugin

Tags: customization, shortcode

I have this shortcode code:

```
add_shortcode( 'dashtest', function () {

$stringtest = "This is $wpc_cf_scorp";
    echo $stringtest;
} );
```

It is attempting to pull in a custom field created by a plugin - I've been fiddling with this, but can't seem wrap my head around it - is there a special way to call in a custom field from a plugin to a shortcode? Thanks!

Comment: In your callback function, you doesn't seem to be fetching any custom field. Variable `$wpc_cf_scorp` seems undefined.

Comment: thanks! That sent me to what feels a bit closer, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull in a custom user field would this be something in get_user_meta() ?

Comment: Yes you can use get_user_meta to fetch custom user related field

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
add_shortcode( 'dashtest', function () {
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

  $key = 'user_wpc';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
    

if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo do_shortcode('[userwpcode key="'.$user_last.'/edit"]');
}
} );
```